# Notification Center (OS X) - variable as title

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsusernotificationcenter

I have problem with set variable in content of Notification Center. This is my code

```
NSUserNotification *notification = [[NSUserNotification alloc] init];
[notification setTitle:@"version of app"];
[notification setInformativeText:@"message"];
// Delay of pop-up notification
[notification setDeliveryDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:0 sinceDate:[NSDate date]]];
// Sound of notification
//[notification setSoundName:NSUserNotificationDefaultSoundName];
 NSUserNotificationCenter *center = [NSUserNotificationCenter defaultUserNotificationCenter];
[center scheduleNotification:notification];
```

How I can add CFBundleVersion to content of notification?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although this has nothing to do with notification center, you should just create a string with the `CFBundleVersion`.

```
NSString *version  = [[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"CFBundleVersion"];
NSString *title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Version %@", version];
```

an then just set the title variable as the title:

```
[notification setTitle:title];
```